# Drawing a dashed/dotted line with an arrowhead in Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs6

I am using Adobe Photoshop CS6 and I am trying to draw a dashed/dotted line with an arrowhead. This is the sort of thing I am looking for:

[image: Arrow drawn successfully with dashes]

Using the line tool I can successfully draw an unbroken (ie. normal) line with an arrowhead.

 Using the pen tool I can successfully draw a dashed/dotted line without an arrowhead.

If I use the line tool to draw a dashed line with an arrowhead, I end up with something like this:

[image: Photoshop drawing line incorrectly]

Photoshop apparently considers the arrow a shape (not surprisingly) and dashes the line border only.

How can I draw a dashed/dotted line with an arrowhead on it?

Comment: Another solution is to create a path and use the shape tool options to add dashing. However, you will need to add the arrowhead manually (e.g. with the shape tool).

Comment: Hey Adobe! Add a dashed option to the Line Tool already!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not choose the line tool for this, so if you're OK with using shapes instead, here's how you can do it.

**1)** Create an arrow shape (custom shape).

[image]

---

**2)** Extend the nodes so that the arrow becomes longer.

[image]

---

**3)** Create subtractions in your shape so it appears to be dashed or dotted.

[image]

---

To create an even subtraction of your shape you can do the following:

**1)** Select the arrow shape and choose the rectangular shape tool.

**2)** While holding <kbd>alt</kbd>, draw a rectangular shape near or on the arrow tail, you will see a 'minus' sign which means you're subtracting from the shape.

**3)** Choose the white arrow tool and select the four nodes of the subtraction shape (the rectangel). When the four nodes are selected, copy them by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>. Now paste it (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> or <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>) and move it by choosing the move tool and holding in <kbd>shift</kbd> and using the arrows, this way you can move it without using the mouse which enables you to get exact measures and get the dashes evenly spread.

**4)** Repeat **3** until you have all the dashes done.

You should now have a dashed or dotted arrow in one single shape, which you can extend, copy or do what you need with, like below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks to your instruction, I now have a small, but good looking dashed arrow. However, I can't seem to "extend the nodes so that the arrow becomes longer". Each time I use one of the nodes to make the shape larger (for example from left to right), the arrow stretches. Could you please elaborate on step 2?

Comment: Absolutely. Make sure that you have the 'Direct selection' tool selected, thats the white arrow - not the black arrow.

Select the layer of the shape, and then drag a selection on the leftmost edge of your arrow. That will select all nodes that are within that are. The selected nodes will be black the other nodes of the shape, they will be visible but white.

When you have those nodes selected, you can move them around how you want.

Comment: Ok, this works well. But does this mean that each time I want to "extend" or make the arrow longer, I need to manually add subtraction shapes to the arrow's line?

Comment: Yes it does I'm afraid. You could create you own custom shape and save it so that you don't have to redo this often, but when you need to extend it or shorten it then you still will need to modify the shape (extend and subtract or remove nodes).

Comment: To create a shape that is smart enough to add dashes when you increase the length of it, is not possible in Photoshop. There are other software that can do that though, not so much focused on graphics but more on prototyping and flow charting. Omnigraffle (Mac) or Axure (Win) would be the ones I know of if you are looking to work with that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm aware of Omnigraffle, not heard of Axure before. Photoshop suits my needs for now however. The ability to draw dashed arrows is not an important enough a feature to me right now to justify the purchase of yet another piece of software.

Comment: Happy to help, good luck

Comment: This is way too slow, moving the selection using arrows will require many arrow presses just to make *one* move.....